# Is there a term for a function where equal output values must come from only one contiguous range of input values?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for a word to describe a function where every output is guaranteed to have come from exactly one contiguous range of input values.

For example, a monotonic function has this property, but that is too strong: the relative ordering is unimportant.

However, this is a looser guarantee than that the function be invertible.  It's not necessary that it be possible to deduce exactly what the input was for a given output.

For example, a function which produced these results might qualify:

```
x    y
------
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    1
7    1
```

But a function that produced these results would not:

```
x    y
------
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    2
4    3
5    2
6    1
7    1
```

because 2 no longer only occurs within a single range of input values.

Comment: A lemnar function?

Comment: As a generalization of injective function (usually called “one to one” or shortly “1-1”) it has been used “many-one”. In your case, for each output a  there is a range, or an interval of numbers. So a suggestion could be “_interval to one_ function”.

Another option could be “preconnected” function; if you use your definition in the real numbers, the intervals are _connected_, and the __pre__-image of each point must be a connected subset.

Comment: Following Pedro's first observation, I half-jokingly suggest *interjective* :P

Comment: @Pedro Sánchez Terraf: your comment contains a good answer. Please include your answer in an answer.

Comment: @aLoveOfSurf Really? Perhaps I can put it as an answer, specially because there are no others.

Answer (score 0):

Following @aLoveOfSurf suggestion, I'm making my comment into an answer. Nevertheless, I must disclaim that I don't know about any established terminology for this kind of functions.

---

As a generalization of injective function (usually called “one to one” or shortly “1-1”) it has been used “many-one”. In your case, for each output a there is a range, or an interval of numbers. So a suggestion could be “*interval to one* function”. Another option could be “preconnected” function; if you use your definition in the real numbers, the intervals are *connected*, and the **pre**-image of each point must be a connected subset.